# Create script to manage service

Tags: bash, scripting

i need your support to create a script necessary to deploy, start and stop a service from one server to the others server. This service is a jar with a properties file.

I would create a menu script with more choice.

I've created it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
PS3='Please enter your choice: '
options=("Start" "Stop" "Deploy" "Quit")
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
case $opt in
"Start Shaw")
echo "you chose choice 1"
;;
"Stop Shaw")
echo "you chose choice 2"
;;
"Check Shaw Status")
echo "you chose choice 3"
;;
"Quit")
break
;;
*) echo "invalid option $REPLY";;
esac
done
```

i don't know how to connect the choices to the various functions.

Start function:

I thought of such a thing:

```
function start_service ( )
{
ssh $1 'nohup /data/jdk1.8.0_151/bin/java -jar -Xmx1024M /data/apps/file.jar &'
}
echo "Starting servers"
for serv_name in $( cat /data/server_list/list.txt )
do start_service ${serv_name} &
echo $! > pid.file &
sleep 5
done
```

where list.txt is a file with all the servers where this service need to be start. The problem is that i need that the file pid.file is created on each server and that by launching it from the first server, a process is not created on the first server for each server listed but one process for each server.

Stop:

i need that starting from the pid.file, a command that read the file.pid and stop that process like: kill $(cat pid.file)

Deploy:

this is the very problem. I'd like to create a folder where putting the jar file or the properties file inside it, selecting this function, the file is deployed on all servers in the defined paths: jar file: /pathtofile/apps/file.jar file properties: /pathtofile/conf/file.properties

PS: i can't use systemd for security question i don't have root access to the servers.

Comment: There's a lot of questions here. I would recommend refactoring your post to focus on a specific question rather than asking for more general help writing your script.

Comment: can i have an help with the start and stop function....the last request of deploy at the moment it is not necessary. I would receive an help to associate the menu choice with the different functions

Answer (score 0):

SystemD does not work for `root` processes only (that is the system level). You can create a SystemD user service (`systemctl --user ...`).

```
#!/bin/bash
PS3='Please enter your choice: '
options=("Start" "Stop" "Deploy" "Quit")
select opt in "${options[@]}"; do
        case $opt in
                "Start")
                        echo "Starting servers"
                        for serv_name in $( cat /data/server_list/list.txt ); do
                                start_service "$serv_name" &
                                echo $! > "$serv_name".pid & # PID of the background subshell
                                sleep 5
                        done
                ;;
                "Stop")
                        echo "you chose choice 2"
                ;;
                "Deploy")
                        echo "you chose choice 3"
                ;;
                "Quit")
                        break
                ;;
                *) echo "invalid option $REPLY";;
        esac
done
```

Comment: I've tried to use this script but the problem is that after use the option 1, on the first server i see:  process /data/jdk1.8.0_151/bin/java -jar -Xmx1024M /data/app/file.jar but also server 2 process /data/jdk1.8.0_151/bin/java -jar -Xmx1024M /data/app/file.jar; server 3 process.....it is normal?

Comment: @Emanuele The `for serv_name in $( cat /data/server_list/list.txt ); do` is your code, not mine. So I had much reason to assume that is intentional. However, just change it to your needs (which are not really clear).

Comment: this part is only to insert in ssh the name of the server and the file list.txt is a list of the server including the first where the script is launched. I don't know why the service is started correctly on the other but on the first i see 33 process.